# Ehcache - using SelfPopulatingCache when data is not present

Tags: java, ehcache

I am using the EhCache's decorator `SelfPopulatingCache` and have an issue when the cache tries to load a new entry, but it's non-existent (i.e. it doesn't exist in the database).  So the cache will put a `null` value into the cache, to unblock any other gets on the key, but then the next thread will do the same database call because it received 'null' from the cache. which means it thinks the entry needs to be loaded - even though in reality it's null because the data doesn't exists anywhere.  I feel like I'm doing something wrong.

(pseudo code)

```
Value v = cache.get(key); // multiple threads will block here
if (v == null)
   cache.put(key, getValueFromDB()); // this might put a null value
```

My current solution is to not put null, but to put a placeholder `Object` and check for it.

```
Value v = cache.get(key);
if (v == null)
   cache.put(key, getValueFromDB());
else if (v == NOENTRYOBJECT)
   return null;
else
   return v;
```

Thoughts?

Comment: I'm not clear how your pseudo-code relates to `SelfPopulatingCache`. How are you using that?

Comment: cache = SelfPopulatingCache (or BlockingCache) ...  thought that was pretty clear

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We do something similar.  In our case, we enter `Boolean.FALSE` into the cache if the requested key doesn't correspond to a valid item.  It basically tells the calling code that the key that it asked for doesn't match any data.  You need to make one call to the db on the first request for that key to discover that it doesn't correspond to valid data, but subsequent calls are spared the db lookup.  Of course, if data is ever entered into the db for that key, you need to be sure to invalidate that cache entry (otherwise you'll be returning Boolean.FALSE even though there is actual data available).

Not sure if my response helps that much (it's not an alternative approach), but it at least validates that you're not alone in your approach.

BTW, I don't think this is unique to EHCache's SelfPopulatingCache.

Answer (score 1):

The typical pattern is not to recheck the database if the item's **KEY** exists in the cache at all, rather than the **VALUE**.

The pattern is described in the ehcache docs here: [Caching Empty Values](http://ehcache.org/recipes/cachenull.html).

Typically, but not always, `get` returns an `Element`, so `get(id)` won't be null if `put(id, value)` was ever previously called, even if value is null.

Note that this depends on the cache implementation. The ehcache documentation seems to suggest that it should always work, but `BlockingCache` (and its descendants) [does NOT allow putting null values into the cache](http://svn.terracotta.org/svn/ehcache/trunk/core/src/main/java/net/sf/ehcache/constructs/blocking/BlockingCache.java). The base ehcache [`Cache`](http://svn.terracotta.org/svn/ehcache/trunk/core/src/main/java/net/sf/ehcache/Cache.java) object does allow null values to be stored in the cache (as do many examples and custom implementations).

In all I think the solution you already have (placeholder value object), also works and should achieve the same result as the ehcache base `Cache` class and documentation.

Comment: Actually that's not true - if you look at the code for BlockingCache and the put(..) method - if value == null it removes the key from the cache.  So put(id, null) effectively puts nothing in the cache, the next get for id will return null - not and Element.

Comment: Hmmm. I haven't looked at the code, so that would be the definitive source. But then that would seem to completely contradict the Ehcache documentation. I am not sure how else that "Caching Empty Values" example would work if you can't cache a null value (it explicitly tells you to do that). I'll look closer at the code when I get a chance, but I *think* I recall having done that in the past and it worked fine (not sure mind you, vague recollection, I'll also write a simple test to confirm/deny).

Comment: I see what it is. My cache implementation isn't using any of the built in Ehcache impls, or of course SelfPopulatingCache. My put method uses a boolean that is set on the cache implementation named: putNullInCache. It defaults to true, and so allows put to store null. So it depends on the cache impl, and you're completely right about SelfPopulatingCache. I'll update my "answer" just for future reference for anyone when I get a chance -- but it is indeed wrong ;). In all I think what you are doing has the same net effect anyway.

Comment: I've updated the answer to reflect what I've learned here, just for future reference (it's not the "correct" answer, but I think leaving it makes more sense than deleting it because it attempts to clarify why this works sometimes, and doesn't other times).

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking you need to look into the CacheElementFactory.  I had implemented this under spring for a project that I was working on to demand load information into the cache, if there was a cache miss an attempt was made to load it in from the database.  I can't remember specifically what I did on this though and I think this would unfortunately result in a request being made to the database for every pass that requested the missing key.