# How to cache null values with Ehcache 3

Tags: null, ehcache, ehcache-3

I need to cache null values with Ehcache 3.
For Ehcache 2 I found examples like here:

- http://www.ehcache.org/documentation/2.8/recipes/cachenull.html

```java
// cache an explicit null value:
cache.put(new Element("key", null));

Element element = cache.get("key");

if (element == null) {

// nothing in the cache for "key" (or expired) ...
} else {

// there is a valid element in the cache, however getObjectValue() may be null:

Object value = element.getObjectValue();

if (value == null) {

    // a null value is in the cache ...

} else {

    // a non-null value is in the cache ...
```

- https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/60393/using-ehcache-the-right-way

Are there examples for this for Ehcache 3 as it seems net.sf.ehcache.Element doesn't exist anymore?

I have also seen this comment: https://github.com/ehcache/ehcache3/issues/1607

> Indeed, you cannot cache a null value, this is also the behaviour of the JCache specification.
>   If you need this in your application, either create a sentinel value or wrap your values from your application.

Of course I could build some logic if my return object is null put it to an other Set were I store only my keys for null elements. Of course also for reading I need to check my ehcache and my "special" Set.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your question contains the answer, you need either to use the [null object pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Object_pattern) or a related solution to wrap / hide your `null`s.

There is no, and there will not be, support for `null` key or values in Ehcache 3.

Comment: Thanks so far. Just thought there could be also some kind of recipe as for Ehcache2. I think I will go with something like described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4473579/ehcache-using-selfpopulatingcache-when-data-is-not-present using `Boolean.FALSE or whatever in case of null.

Comment: Beware that `Optional` is not `Serializable` and so will not work for any cache beyond heap.

Answer (score 1):

I simply created a null placeholder class.

```
public class EHCache3Null implements Serializable {
  private static final long serialVersionUID = -1542174764477971324L;
  private static EHCache3Null INSTANCE = new EHCache3Null();

  public static Serializable checkForNullOnPut(Serializable object) {
    if (object == null) {
      return INSTANCE;
    } else {
      return object;
    }
  }

  public static Serializable checkForNullOnGet(Serializable object) {
    if (object != null && object instanceof EHCache3Null) {
      return null;
    } else {
      return object;
    }
  }
}
```

Then when I use the cache I have the following on my put operation:

```
cache.put(element.getKey(), EHCache3Null.checkForNullOnPut(element.getValue()));
```

and then this on my get operation:

```
Serializable value = EHCache3Null.checkForNullOnGet((Serializable) cache.get(key));
```